# Ruby replace substring of string representation of a JSON

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string as follows, which is in JSON format:

```
  test_geometry_profile =
  '{
    "geometryProfile": {

      "SPEEDSeedModel0.osm": {
        "WWR": 0.5,
        "Orientation": 0.0
      },

      "SPEEDSeedModel1.osm": {
        "WWR": 0.6,
        "Orientation": 0.0
      }
    }
  }'
```

I would like to replace the substring `SPEEDSeedModel1.osm` in this string with `'TestOSM_radiantDOAS.osm'`.

I used the code:

```
test_geometry_profile.sub("SPEEDSeedModel1.osm", 'TestOSM_radiantDOAS.osm')
```

However, this fails to work. Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working, but [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sub) returns a copy of the string with the substitution made. You can see this by doing running:

```
test_geometry_profile =
  '{
    "geometryProfile": {

      "SPEEDSeedModel0.osm": {
        "WWR": 0.5,
        "Orientation": 0.0
      },

      "SPEEDSeedModel1.osm": {
        "WWR": 0.6,
        "Orientation": 0.0
      }
    }
  }'

puts test_geometry_profile
puts test_geometry_profile.sub("SPEEDSeedModel1.osm", 'TestOSM_radiantDOAS.osm')
puts test_geometry_profile
```

The second value output will have the change made, and the third is the original string. What you want is [`sub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21), which changes the string in place:

```
puts test_geometry_profile
puts test_geometry_profile.sub!("SPEEDSeedModel1.osm", 'TestOSM_radiantDOAS.osm')
puts test_geometry_profile
```

Now the second and third values have the new string.